# Missing a custom icon in a Bootstrap 4 carousel

Tags: icons, custom-font

I'm working on this:
http://carousel7.bitballoon.com/

I have read various Q&A and used the Developer view of my code.

When a user clicks "next" or "back" (custom icons), he should be able to see the next slide in the carousel. I have created the carouse with Bootstrap 4 from Bootstrap:

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/carousel/#multiple-carousels

I've tried to link it to a "next" icon in an "icons" folder. I had also tried to create a custom font (for the "next" and "back") before, but it did not work.

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-   ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="carousel-item active">
<img src="images/featured_image_grey1.jpg" alt="First slide">
</div>
<div class="carousel-item">
<img src="images/featured_image_grey2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
</div>

</div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="icon-back" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</a>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```css
    .right .carousel-control {
    }
     .left .carousel-control {
    }


    .carousel-control {
    background-color: transparent !IMPORTANT ;
    background-image: none; !IMPORTANT;
  font-size: 80px !IMPORTANT;
  text-shadow: none;
    color: red;
    }


.body {
    padding: 100px 0 !IMPORTANT;
    font-weight: 40px !IMPORTANT;
    background-color: transparent !IMPORTANT; 
    background-image: 'images/background.png' !IMPORTANT; 
}
.container:first-child {margin-top: 90px !IMPORTANT;
}


.nav-link {
    font-family: "DIN Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif !IMPORTANT;
    padding: 3px 0 !IMPORTANT;
    font-weight: 40px !IMPORTANT;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #ff9999 !IMPORTANT;
}
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link:hover, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.active:hover, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.open, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.open:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link.open:hover, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .open>.nav-link, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .open>.nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .open>.nav-link:hover {
    color: #ff3333 !IMPORTANT;
}


/* START new icon */
.icon-back {
    background-image: url("icons/back.svg") !IMPORTANT;
    font-size: 100% !IMPORTANT;

}
.icon-next {
    background-image: url("icons/next.svg") !IMPORTANT;
    font-size: 100% !IMPORTANT;
}
/* END new icon */
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now corrected my CSS: the two new control icons now work!
See here:
http://carousel8.bitballoon.com/

- I am now fixing the size and positioning of the new carousel controls icons